# Integration between Codemirror and Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, codemirror

I want to realize one behavior: when I select specific template from ComboBox appearing code in codemirror textarea. 
Please, see my fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/GEJsu/1/

```
    function Template(initialTemplate) {
        var self = this;
        self.name = ko.observable(initialTemplate);
        self.code = ko.computed({
            read: function () {
                return self.name().Code;
            },
            write: function (value) {

            },
            owner: this
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your code. There were a lot of useless code. So please let me know if I deleted too much.

This is the view :

```
<select data-bind="options: availableTemplates,
                   value: selectedTemplate,
                   optionsText: 'Name'"></select>
<br />
<div data-bind="with: selectedTemplate">
    <textarea cols="60" rows="8" style="background: lightblue"
     data-bind="value: Code,
                codemirror: { 'lineNumbers': true, 'mode': 'javascript' }">
     </textarea>
</div>
```

And the view model :

```
// Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
function ValidationViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.selectedTemplate = ko.observable();

    // Non-editable data - would come from the server
    self.availableTemplates = [{
        Name: "Range Validation",
        Code: "var minValue = 'A';\r\nvar maxValue = 'Z';\r\n\r\nreturn (e.value >= minValue && e.value <= maxValue) \r\n   ? true \r\n   : 'this is all wrong!';"
    }, {
        Name: "DateTime",
        Code: "var newDate = new Date(e.value);\r\n\r\nif (newDate != 'Invalid Date')\r\n   return true; \r\n\r\nreturn 'value is not a valid dateTime';"
    }, {
        Name: "Decimal",
        Code: "if (e.value == null || e.value.length == 0)\r\n   return 'please, type something'; \r\n\r\nreturn isFinite(e.value);"
    }];


}
```

[**See Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UkHu6/1/)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I forgot to join the fiddle.
Please could you explain what's not working (based on the fiddle).

Comment: The code from selected template has appeared into common textarea, but I would that the code has appeared in codemirror area.                http://jsfiddle.net/6sd7f/3/                                       If I add **ko.bindingHandlers.codemirror** it isn't work correctly(the code hasn't appeared in codemirror area).                           http://jsfiddle.net/6sd7f/4/                                         What I do wrong? Sorry for stupid questions, but I just study and thank you for the fast answer.